# mysql substring get only characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have records like these:

RCV0001 
RCV0002 
RTN0003 
RTN0004 
SLE0005 
RCV0006

I want to query for records that start with 'RCV' only and display only records.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
select substring(documentnumber, 1)
LIKE '%RCV%'
from transactionheader
```

But I'm not getting my desired result. Any ideas? I'd gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use `RCV%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will need to add a filter on the where statement

```
select documentnumber
from transactionheader
where  documentnumber  LIKE 'RCV%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression in the select list of your query returns a boolean, so the query will only return 0, 1 or NULL for every row in the table.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(documentnumber, 1) LIKE '%RCV%'
  FROM transactionheader
```

For every row in the table, the first character of documentnumber will be inspected to see if it contains the string 'RCV', which will never be true. The query is going to return 0 or NULL for every row.

---

There is more than one query that will return documentnumber that start with 'RCV'. Here is one example:

```
SELECT h.documentnumber
  FROM transactionheader h
 WHERE h.documentnumber LIKE 'RCV%'
```

The `WHERE` clause specifies the conditional tests that will be performed on each row, only rows that "satisfy" the predicate will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query has no WHERE clause so everything is being selected. Also, I would recommend using [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) instead. Here is my rewritten example.

```
SELECT substring(documentnumber, 1)
FROM transaction header
WHERE documentnumber REGEXP '^RCV'
;
```